# How to use npm install while it don't work

Tags: javascript, json, cmd, bots, discord

first im french so i got a bad english
second: First time posting in this site so Hello !
I need help for programing a new bot, i follow this guide "

https://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-make-a-discord-bot/ "but something happen

so i just type npm install discord.io winston –save in the cmd at the right folder but this happen
0 info it worked if it ends with ok

1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe',

1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',

1 verbose cli   'install',

1 verbose cli   'discord.io',

1 verbose cli   'winston',

1 verbose cli   '-save' ]

2 info using npm@6.4.1

3 info using node@v10.15.0

4 verbose npm-session a734d63e069c8d38

5 silly install loadCurrentTree

6 silly install readLocalPackageData

7 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 2ms

8 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 11ms

9 verbose stack Error: Failed to parse json

9 verbose stack Unexpected token “ in JSON at position 3 while parsing near '{

9 verbose stack “name”: “greeter-bot...'

9 verbose stack     at parseError (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:452:11)

9 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:104:26)

9 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:51:5

9 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16

9 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (internal/fs/read_file_context.js:53:3)

10 verbose cwd C:\Users\ZeBoss\Desktop\bot ds

11 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299

12 verbose argv "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program

Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "discord.io" "winston" "-save"

13 verbose node v10.15.0

14 verbose npm  v6.4.1

15 error file C:\Users\ZeBoss\Desktop\bot ds\package.json

16 error code EJSONPARSE

17 error JSON.parse Failed to parse json

17 error JSON.parse Unexpected token “ in JSON at position 3 while parsing near '{

17 error JSON.parse “name”: “greeter-bot...'

18 error JSON.parse Failed to parse package.json data.

18 error JSON.parse package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.

19 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

I try a few time while using npm cache clean --force but nothing happen

I think my message is long enough so i won't copypasta my code, but i literraly copy paste it from the guide and I just changed the token.
Also i know that it might be obvious for you but im not a good programer so please be nice ^^

EDIT: Someone asked to write package.json here so :

```
{
“name”: “greeter-bot”,
“version”: “1.0.0”,
“description”: “My First Discord Bot”,
“main”: “bot.js”,
“author”: “Your Name”,
“dependencies”: {}
}
```

Comment: Your package.json file is malformed.

Comment: can u paste your package.json file after pressing Ctrl+K so that it will be shortened height with grey background.

Comment: or you can use jsonlint.com and copy paste your package.json which will tell which line your package.json is having error

Comment: On jsonlint.com I don't really understand the error ._.

Comment: To those of you who down voted This question does not deserve down votes it is correctly asked just not very well formatted. don't do something unless its for a reason :(

Answer (score 1):

In your `package.json` file you are using wrong quotation marks. Your code uses `“”` instead of `""`. Just replace them and you should be fine.